# Utilizing the MySQL "Comments" section to process variables in PHP, good or bad idea?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Looking for a better way to pull table column names I came across the "INFORMATION_SCHEMA". I realized while I was pulling column names, I could also pull other data from the column like "Type", "Length/Values" and even "Comments".

This gave me an idea, I could use the values in these columns to process form variables and then insert them with [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). For example, I can check for int or varchar in the "Type" column to create my "i" or "s" data in bind_param.

Some of the form data I wanted to use various [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) statements or other sanitizing features on, so I added items to the "Comments" section, created a deliminator and then [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them so I can process everything in a loop. An example to process a phone number using double pipe delimiters, Comments section = "^0-9||10". If isset(explode[0]), remove all non numeric characters and if explode[1], make sure it has at least 10 numbers left after stripping out non numbers.

So is this a terrible idea? I heard that accessing the Information_Schema can be slow on massive databases, but would it be an issue on smaller databases? Is there something else I'm missing? I really like the idea of using the "Comments" section but before I jump in with both feet, I would love some confirmation that I haven't made a huge mistake.

Comment: If you do this, you have to be very rigorous about filling in the comments, and typos could mess things up. Will writing a generic database API that uses this really be that much easier than using context-specific validation in the application scripts?

Comment: What @Barmar said. This is problematic for a lot of reasons.

Comment: I should have mentioned I use phpMyAdmin, "comments" appear directly under the table names and are quite easy to view/edit. The form data I'm currently working on is for a Restful API script were the sender might change the amount and type of data sent at infrequent intervals (out of my control). I was looking for a fluid way that when I needed to modify the parameters of a variable or add a new variable, instead of opening up my code or modifying two tables, I could open up a single table in phpMyAdmin and quickly make a few adjustments without needing to open or modify the php script.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this, but it (1) requires at least one extra trip to the database (making the code slower), (2) means you must maintain the comments column diligently, and (3) makes your code less transparent. This is true regardless of whether the database is "massive" or "smaller."

Say you're inserting the string `"foo"` into an `int` field. If you have the value type in your PHP code, the error is easy to spot. If you have to go examine the table to find the problem, the error is masked.

What if you change your schema? If you use a literal `s` or `i`, you can catch places in your code where you are using the wrong value type. If you rely on the database to tell you the value type, you're reduced to using a debugger to look at actual data *values* to see if they will work, post-schema-change.

In short, you *could* do this, but you're likely to create more problems than you solve. A better method is to save the validation rules you want to use, whether in a file (say, JSON format) or in the database, but save them somewhere not in the comments. You don't want to have to do an `ALTER TABLE` just to tweak a comment to update a regex or something.

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin, so changing a comment in the database isn't very difficult. I used to store my data processing in a separate table, which meant I still had to pull data from two tables. If I'm already going to the Information_Schema to pull column names, then grabbing some extra data should be an extra lift. Unless of course using the Information_Schema to pull column names is a bad idea, not sure, it's just how everyone on here in another thread agreed was the best method.

Comment: @Mike it's not that it's *difficult* to store the info in the comment; it's that it's a bad idea because you have to `ALTER TABLE` to change it, which is slow and locks the entire table. And if you really want to store business rules (which is what these regexes, etc., are) in the database, then you should use a separate table for lots of reasons. What you're proposing will be difficult to maintain, at best. It's fine to pull column *names* from information_schema, but that's very different from storing logic in the column comments.

Comment: Modifications to the table/regex aren't going to be very often, were talking maybe one time in an entire month at most. I'm using phpMyAdmin which shows the "comments" directly under the column names so they are easy to view and modify using that program. I've always used 2 separate tables to accomplish this before, but when there was a problem or if I needed to make a change, I had to open two separate tables and also had to create unique identifiers to link the tables. With this method I can open a single table to view the data and also see how that data is processed all at one time.

Comment: @Mike Well, you asked if this was a good idea. I'm telling you, it's not. It makes your application very brittle in a lot of ways, requires schema modifications if you want to change a simple validation rule, and makes debugging much harder because the logic is broken up into two places, one of which is not a place intended to store code or logic of any kind. I understand that phpMyAdmin makes this *easy* to change; that doesn't make it *a good idea*. You're welcome to disregard the advice, but I'm trying to answer your question, "So is this a terrible idea?" Respectfully: yes. Yes, it is.

Comment: I do appreciate your comments, I was looking for red flag situation where somehow this would be unsecure or cause crashes, but it sounds like it's not that it will cause major errors, just considered a bad practice. I'll definitely rethink how/if I try to implement this. Thanks for the help.